# Get active tab value in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code.

```
<fieldset>
   <label>Work Order For <span class="req">
    <span class="gray">(choose one)</span>*</span>
   </label>
    <ul class="multi-list tabs">
        <li id="resident-tab" class="width-33 selected"><a data-href=".tab-1" onclick="setResidentPropertyUnitTab( '1' )">Resident</a></li>
        <li id="unit-tab" class="width-33 "><a data-href=".tab-2" class="even" onclick="setResidentPropertyUnitTab( '0' )">Unit</a></li>
        <li id="property-tab" class="width-33 "><a class="last" data-href=".tab-3" onclick="setResidentPropertyUnitTab( '2' )">Property</a></li>
      </ul>
     <div class="tabs-content">
       <div class="tab-1">
  <fieldset>
     <label>Permission To Enter</label>
     <div class="switch bg-green" id="js-permission-to-enter">
       <ul>
           <li><span>YES</span></li>
           <li><span>NO</span></li>
       </ul>
        <span class="switcher on">II</span>
        <input name="maintenance_request[permission_to_enter]" value="1" id="permission_to_enter" type="hidden">
   </div>
 </fieldset>
 </div>
   <div class="tab-2 hide" id="buildingUnit">
      <fieldset>
           <label>Permission To Enter</label>
           <div class="switch js-permission-to-enter bg-red">
             <ul>
               <li><span>YES</span></li>
                <li><span>NO</span></li>
             </ul>
            <span class="switcher off">II</span>
        </div>
            <input name="maintenance_request[permission_to_enter]" value="0" id="permission_to_enter" type="hidden">
 </fieldset>
  </div>
```

I want active tab value from multi_tabs selected. At a time only one tab is selected and from selected tab I want value of #permission_to_enter  variable using jQuery.

Comment: Where is the tab switching code? Also note that ID's must be unique by definition

Comment: $('body').on('click','.tabs li a',function(e) {

  if( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) {

   return false;

  } else {

   var tabTarget = $(this).attr('data-href');

   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('selected');

   $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

   $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(tabTarget).siblings().hide();

   $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(tabTarget).fadeIn(300);

   e.preventDefault();

  }

 });

Answer (score -1):

You can easily implement using selector in jquery and data attribute

```
$($('.selected a').data("href")+' #permission_to_enter').val()
```

Above code will return you the value of `permission_to_enter` input of active tab.

Comment: which ID are you talking about, and this code works peacefully and properly , i guess you misunderstood the question and definitely doesn't call for a downvote until it decided.

Comment: why you add + in the code  that i don't understand... is it like concatenation ?

Comment: Yes its concatenation `$('.selected a').data("href")` will return active tabs class, and concatinating it with `#permission_to_enter` will give us selector for input box and `.val()`  will return the value

Comment: Yes Ids' must be unique but i have tabs like menu items from which I want to get the value of selected item and particular field value which is present on both tabs.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail : I tried for your suggested solution. but it failed while concatenating with first tab.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6f127ftb/ have a look at this fiddle i put selected on second tab and its returning correct value in console.